# Strings with same value not seen as equal

Tags: scala

I have the following code in a test file:

```
println("myVarXml: " + myVarXml)
println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n</HDStream>")
```

Outputs:

```
myVarXml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
</HDStream>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
</HDStream>
```

And:

```
 assert(myVarXml == "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n</HDStream>")
```

That outputs:

```
]
</HDStream>" did not equal "...oding="iso-8859-1"?>[]
</HDStream>"
```

The strings are the same. Why is the assert failing?

Comment: You probably have `^M` (or, perhaps, another unprintable character) in the value of `myVarXml` before `</HDStream>`

Comment: Ok, so how do I clean the String?

Comment: That would depend on what exactly you mean by "clean". Something like `myVarXml.replaceAll("""[^\w<>?.\s-]""", "")` might work, but it's hard to tell if that's really what you are looking for without knowing what you are trying to do, where your data comes from, and why it needs "cleaning" in the first place.

Comment: For just line endings, normalize with `s.lines.mkString("\n")`, for testing purposes.